# Need help converting this number system

Tags: python, python-2.7

So i'm supposed to convert Babylonian characters to number values so that:

```
"<" = 10
"T" = 1
"\" = 0
```

When I put the values in, it should add the sum of those numbers, so  `babylonian( "TTT")` would equal `3` because there are 3 "1" values.

So far I have this code below, but I can't seem to get the sum, but rather just get the individual numbers.

```
def babylonian(symbols) :
    lst = []
    for str in symbols:
        sum = 0
        for i in str:
            if i == "<":
                sum = sum + 10
            elif i == "T":
                sum = sum + 1
            elif i == "\\":
                sum = sum + 0
        lst.append(sum)
    return lst
```

Comment: what purpose has  '\' ? it does not change the sum. so '<<<\\\\\\\\\' is 30 as well. Or should it be 3000000000?

Comment: where and how do you call your function, what is the expected and what the gotten result?

Comment: `babylonian(["TTT"])` or remove the first `for` since it seems like it is expceting `symbols` to be an array, but  just a guess, never did anything with Python

Comment: @PatrickArtner but why the **two** loops? (sometimes static types have an advantage....)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a dictionary to save the mapping? You code would become much more simpler

```
def babylonian(symbols) :
    sum = 0
    values = {'<' : 10, 'T': 1 , '\\': 1}
    for str in symbols:
        sum += values[str]
    return sum


print(babylonian( "TTT"))
```

Comment: A bit shorter: `return sum(map(values.get, symbols))` or `return sum(values[x] for x in symbols)`

Comment: @tobias_k I won't suggest it since the OP is a newbie and using functional programming might be little too overwhelming for him now.

Comment: That may be, but IMHO list comprehensions are an incredibly useful feature of Python that can't be learned too early. Agreed this should not be the _only_ suggestion, though. Also, you emphasize using a dictionary, but that part was not actually the problem with OP's code, but the redundant loop and storing the "sums" in a list.